# Protecting CSV information when using data for D3 Graph

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

My D3 graph uses `d3.csv` to call a `csv` so it can generate the graph. However, the individual rows in the `csv` are sensitive information. Is there a way to "hide" or protect the `csv` from public eyes while keeping the graph viewable to the public?

Comment: ah sorry about the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

No.
There is nothing you can do to protect a file after you have served it to a web browser